# Transfering order to conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Suppose that $Q\sim P$, $X,Y\in L^2(\mathcal{F})$
 are such that 
$$
\mathbb{E}_{Q}[(X-Y)^2]
\leq
\mathbb{E}_{P}[(X-Y)^2].
$$
Under what circumstances, can we conclude that 
$$
\mathbb{E}_{Q}[(
  \mathbb{E}_{Q}[X|\mathcal{G}]-
Y)^2]
\leq
\mathbb{E}_{P}[(
\mathbb{E}_{P}[X|\mathcal{G}]
-Y)^2]?
$$
Where $\mathcal{G}$ is a fixed sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward calculation shows that the second inequality holds if, in addition,
\begin{align}
&\mathsf{E}_P\operatorname{Var}_P(X\mid \mathcal{G})-\mathsf{E}_Q\operatorname{Var}_Q(X\mid \mathcal{G})\\
&\qquad\le 2\left(\mathsf{E}_P\operatorname{Cov}_P(X,Y\mid \mathcal{G})-\mathsf{E}_Q\operatorname{Cov}_Q(X,Y\mid \mathcal{G})\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Okay, but I was maybe looking for a deeper sufficient condition....